# Swift Syntax - Method in Square Brackets, Expression of Type [Void] is unused

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, syntax

I'm currently working on a project where table view cells get updated, and the tableview needs to update to fix the added content. While searching for how this could be done, I came across code which suggested to add this:

```
 [tableView .beginUpdates()]
 [tableView .endUpdates()]
```

which not only updates the tableview, but also animates it too.

How does this syntax work? Does it have a name? I'm just a bit confused by it. To me, the square brackets [] are referring to arrays, tableView is the variable referring to the UITableView, and beginUpdates() is a function. The code works but I'm getting a warning saying "Expression of type [Void] is unused.

Comment: just remove the `[]` and everything works the same way. It is storing the "returned" Void of the method calls into an array.

Comment: It looks like a mix-up of Objective-C and Swift syntax. Basically square brackets in Swift are only used to indicate arrays, dictionaries and subscription.

Comment: wow that makes much more sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `[` and `]`

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```